# Controlled phase shift gate

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

How does a controlled R gate look like (matrixwise)?
And how to generate CCR, CCCR and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/quantum-gates) and it seems like for a gate

$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{00}   & x_{10}\\
x_{00}   & x_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

its controlled variant would be:
$$
CU=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & x_{00} & x_{01} \\  
0 & 0 & x_{10} & x_{11} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence for R, which is
$$
R(\theta) =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0\\ 
0 & e^{i \theta} \end{bmatrix}
$$

CR would be:
$$
CR(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i \theta} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**P.S.: Please, correct me if I'm wrong.**

Comment: Yes, you are right. Similarly you can get a C...CU gate, $U$ is in the right bottom corner of a C...CU gate, other diagonal elements are ones and other non-diagonal elements are zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The phase shift is a family of single-qubit gates that map the basis states ket(0) to ket(0)  and ket(1) to exp(i theta)* ket(1)  so by using this we can find matrix of controlled phase shift operator.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please use proper formating of maths with Latex.